# sending forum in background without page reload

Tags: php, html, ajax, database

i have a php forum which sends information to my database and sends it back to that page but i am stuck with a little problem. when i submit the forum the page fully reloads. which i don't want. to accomplish what i need the forum to reload in the background. i have looked for a way to do this but none of them could help me do this task. here is the code bellow.

```html
//this is the php file which runs the fourm

<?php
header("Location: localhost:8888"); 


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$value = $_POST['firstname'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname) VALUES ('$value')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<a href=https://twitter.com/angela_bradley>My Twitter</a>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
//this is the fourm
<form action="demo.php" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: thanks @Darren i have tried looking for how to use it with that but i can't find how i can.

Comment: check my answer. it has all you need step by step

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your Insert query code to separate file. lets say example `register.php` and it should return simple text like success else with error message. in this way, you can easily check the data in Ajax success callback.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$value = $_POST['firstname'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname) VALUES ('$value')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

If you want to return JSON, you can update your PHP Code like below.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   $message = "success";
} else {
   $message = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$result = '{"message": ' + $message + '}';
echo json_encode($result);
```

Add Id to your Form to identify easily through DOM

```
<form id="target" action="demo.php" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Using `$.submit` will be triggered when user submit and JSON data will be generated using `serialize` and `$.post` help to do ajax post.

Add this just before body end with surrounded script tag

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var jqxhr = $.post( "register.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        alert( "success" );
      })
      .done(function() {
        alert( "second success" );
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
      })
      .always(function() {
        alert( "finished" );
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: please could you help and tell me what the last section is and were do i put it

Comment: just below your </form> tag

Comment: @Jack, that is self explanatory. anyways updated the answer and better for other user.